# My Cordova project not responding to jquery

Tags: jquery, iphone, xcode, html, cordova

I've been looking for the last two days, and I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm struggling to get a small app to list all our company's employees in a searchable list view. Although I managed to get the code working in both the simulator and my iphone, the pieces regarding jquery to create the searchable listview are not showing up. I think I double and triple checked by js and css links, but still I'm clueless. Any help would be really appreciated.

BTW, I'm using Xcode 4.5.2, Jquery-mobile-1.2.0 and cordova-2.3.

Here is the index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />


</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header" id="header" class="header">
            <h1>MIT Employees</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" id="header2">
            <h2>Select Employee</h2>
        </div><!-- /content -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true"><div data-role="content" id="employeeList"></div></ul>
    </div>

    <div id="busy"/>Loading...</div>

    <script src="js/phonegap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="js/getEmpList.js"></script>
    <script src="js/employ.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here the Javascript:

```
var db;
var dbCreated = false;

var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { vScrollbar: true, hScrollbar:false, hScroll: false });


//add listener when device ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


//function will be called when device ready
function onDeviceReady() {
db = window.openDatabase("EmployeeDirectoryDB", "1.0", "MIT Employee Database", 200000);
if (dbCreated)
    db.transaction(getEmployees, transaction_error);
else
    db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_error, populateDB_success);
}
function transaction_error(tx, error) {
$('#busy').hide();
alert("Database Error: " + error);
}

function populateDB_success() {
dbCreated = true;
db.transaction(getEmployees, transaction_error);
}

function getEmployees(tx) {
var sql = "select * from employees order by lname, fname";
tx.executeSql(sql, [], getEmployees_success);
}

function getEmployees_success(tx, results) {
$('#busy').hide();
var len = results.rows.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    var employee = results.rows.item(i);
    $('#employeeList').append('<li data-icon="arrow-r"><a href="employeedetails.html?id=' + employee.id + '">' +
                              '<p class="line2">' + employee.empid + ' ' + employee.lname + ', ' + employee.fname + '</a></li>');
}
setTimeout(function(){
           scroll.refresh();
           },100);
db = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The order of my linked jquery scripts was wrong.

It now appears the filtering option. Although, the keyboard is not active. I'll keep looking for this one.